# Getting image from public folder

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get image from public folder in laravel inside blankURL : 'public/assets/images/blank.gif', in this path

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.zoomple').zoomple({ 

  // specifies the source for the blank image. 
  blankURL : 'public/assets/images/blank.gif', 

  // background color
  bgColor : '#90D5D9', 

  // if set to true, the magnifier will follow the mouse, if set to false, the magnifier will sit attached on the side of the image.
  attachWindowToMouse: true, 

  // when attachWindowToMouse is set to false, the window will sit on the side of the image. 
  // This property defines on which corner of the image, the magnifier will sit (e.g. windowPosition : {x:’right’,y:’bottom’}). 
  // Possible values for x: ‘right’, ‘left’. 
  // Possible values for y: ‘top’, ‘bottom’.
  windowPosition: {x:'right',y:'bottom'}, 

  // specifies the source for the “loading” image. 
  loaderURL : 'public/assets/images/loader.gif', 
  });
});
```

Comment: What you had tried so far ?

Comment: blankURL : 'public/assets/images/blank.gif', in this path

Comment: remove public from url

Comment: Why don't you try using `{{ assets('public/your/path/to/the/image.jpg') }}` or modify the asset function itself?

`if (! function_exists('asset')) {
    /**
     * Generate an asset path for the application.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @return string
     */
    function asset($path, $secure = null)
    {
        return app('url')->asset("public/".$path, $secure);
    }
}`